# Storing WCF Observables in stand alone StreamInsight Server

Tags: streaminsight

I am using WCF Observables based on samples:

var observableWcfSource = app.DefineObservable(() => new WcfObservable())

It works but it does not register the source in the server so when i explore my stand alone StreamInsight service with Event Flow Debugger, i cannot see the source (and use it in other queries). How can i register my source?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to deploy it to the server with a unique name. That will let you use it in other queries.

```
observableWcfSource.Deploy("MyNewObservable");
```

More information is available here on MSDN: [Deploying StreamInsight Entities to a StreamInsight Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149394(v=sql.111).aspx)